# Is it possible to insert something into a partial?

Tags: mustache, handlebars.js

Is it possible to use partials as wrapper? Like the following example

I don't want to use a variable like `{{> myPartial foo='bar' }}`

#### someView.hbs

```
{{> myPartial }}
  foo bar 
{{/ myPartial }}
```

#### myPartial.hbs

```
<!-- ... -->
{{myPlaceholder}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. See http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html#partial-block

#### someView.hbs

```
{{#> myPartial }}
  foo bar 
{{/ myPartial }}
```

#### myPartial.hbs

```
<!-- ... -->
{{> @partial-block }}
```